# What is name file responsible for sending email to guests frontend order? Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1

What is name file responsible for sending email to guests frontend order?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give you a precise answer without more details on what you are trying to accomplish. But you can find the classes used by magento 2 to send mail under:

> vendor/magento/framework/Mail/

For example, if you want to change how magento 2 delivers e-mail simply override Transport.php with your own class by creating your own module. Do not modify the original file as this is considered a bad practice for **many** reasons.

Comment: Hi @DustyMan, Thank you for your reply.

order confirmation email is not sent for guest's order only and In the backend shows (The order confirmation email is not sent), if i clicked on send email it sends the message.

Comment: Is your cronjob running?

Comment: Yes everything else with emails sending working fine and i use third party extension https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp.

Comment: That is indeed weird. Is your "Asynchronous sending" setting turned off?

Comment: Yes its turned off :(

Comment: I searched the official repository for any similar case but I didn't find any. Do you have any other module installed other than the SMTP?

Comment: Yes i have, and I tried to disabled all module and the same